# Bug in NearestNeighborGraph

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier, Fixed in 12.2.0**

---

`NearestNeighborGraph` generates incorrectly formatted output on rasterized input. Reported to Wolfram support CASE:4093797

```
$Version
(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

NearestNeighborGraph[
 Rasterize[Style[#, 20], "Image"] & /@ Alphabet[], 
 2,
 VertexLabels -> "Name"
]
```

[image]

The labels are too large.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you are asking for a workaround, you can generate the output you expect with:

```
v = Style[#,20]& /@ Alphabet[];
rv = Rasterize/@v;

NearestNeighborGraph[
    rv,
    2,
    VertexLabels->Thread@Rule[rv,v]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For another workaround, you can set ImageSize:

```
NearestNeighborGraph[
 Rasterize[Style[#, 20], ImageSize -> 10] & /@ Alphabet[], 2, 
 VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]